# Why does CANalyzer not time out after P2ServerMax

Tags: canalyzer, uds

P2ServerMax and P2*ServerMax are configured correctly in CANalyzer.
However, after sending "10 01", it takes 100ms until "50 01" is received and no time-out was detected by CANalyzer.
A "10 78" was not received in between.

How can I solve that?

Comment: There are 0.5 milliseconds between 0.1 ms and 0.6 ms which is far below 50 ms. How do you want CANalyzer to behave?

Comment: sorry it is seconds

Comment: eg. 10 01 -->0.1 s 50 01 --->0.60 s

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the diagnostic configuration dialog where you have configured the P2 times, as well as a screenshot of the trace window, where the SessionStart messages are visible?

Comment: I already tried to improve the description a bit based on the comments, but we need more.
How exactly did you send the diagnostic request with CANalyzer and where exactly did you expect the time-out to be shown in which way?